# iFrame gets loaded automatically whenever my chrome extension is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

so I am a beginner and started making a chrome extension just for fun. It's a basic extension which makes an iframe element on any page. I have added the onClick event listener in my code to trigger the iFrame whenever the extension's logo is clicked . But for some reason whenever I open a new site the iFrame loads automatically. It does load again when I press the chrome extension's icon, but I just cannot make it stop appearing whenever a new site is visited. Here is my code. Any help would be appreciated!

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Sample Extension",
    "action": {},
      "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting","tabs","clipboardRead",
      "clipboardWrite"],
      "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
      },
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["contentscript.js"],
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "all_frames": true
    }],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources": [ "frame.html" ],
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
        }
    ]
}
```

contentscript.js

```
var extensionOrigin = 'chrome-extension://' + chrome.runtime.id;
if (!location.ancestorOrigins.contains(extensionOrigin)) {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('frame.html');
    iframe.style.cssText = 'position:fixed;top:25px ;left:25px;display:block;' +
                           'width:calc(100% - 50px);height:calc(100vh - 50px);z-index:9999; background: none; border: none; border-radius: 10px';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab,tabId) => {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        files: ["contentscript.js"],
        target: {tabId: tab.id}
    })
  });
```

frame.html

```
<style>
html, body, iframe, h2 {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: none;
    color: black;
}
h2 {
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
iframe {
    height: 100vh;
}
</style>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/"></iframe>
```

Comment: Remove `content_scripts` from manifest.json because it declares automatic injection.

Comment: Thanks a lot @wOxxOm I was struggling with this for over 3 hours. This solved the problem. Also, could you suggest any site or place where I could learn about chrome extensions properly?